# Please explain why "Hello world" is printed 3 times?

Tags: c++, virtual-inheritance

Why  is "hello world" printted three times? I don't understand clearly about inheritance virtual in struct with C++.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct BS{
    BS() {
        cout << "hello world" << endl;
    }

    unsigned int color;
};

struct mid1 : virtual public BS { };
struct mid2 : virtual public BS { };
struct mid3 : public BS { };
struct mid4 : public BS { };

struct D : public mid1, public mid2, public mid3, public mid4 { };

int main() {
    D d;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It was printed three times because you wrote code that instructed your computer to print it three times... What's the actual question?

Comment: If the question is indeed "who can explain...?" the answer would be "anyone who read the section on virtual inheritance in C++".

Comment: I agree with jbat100 - why downvote at all, it is clearly a beginner trying to understand what is going on. I would be far better to give no vote and an answer to explain what's happening and where the OP can find full documentation.

Comment: http://codepad.org/jn3H8dpb   warning: virtual base 'BS' inaccessible in 'D' due to ambiguity

Comment: It *is* a good question. If you asked me how many times it could have printed, I'd say from a glance "between 0 and 4 times" (and then, admittedly, I'd have tried it out with lots of intermittant debug output).

Comment: Lacks the minimal understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm stunned by the downvotes and the insulting responses.

`D` has four base classes. Of those, `mid1` has one base class, `virtual BS`, and `mid2 has one base class,`virtual BS`. There are no other uses of`virtual BS`. So`mid1`and`mid2`share one copy of a`BS`object as their virtual base.`mid3`has a **non**-virtual base,`BS`; this is not shared. And`mid4`has a` **non**-virtual base, `BS`; this, too, is not shared. So there are three copies of `BS`: one that is the virtual base of `mid1` and `mid2`, one that is the non-virtual base of `mid3`, and one that is the non-virtual base of `mid4`. Three `BS` objects, so three constructor calls, so three "hello world"s.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this example.
Its more easy to understand. When you create an object of derived class the object calls the constructor of base class first and then its own constructor.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

struct BaseClass{
    BaseClass() 
    {
        cout << "hello world of base class" << endl;
    }
};

struct DerivedClass1 : virtual public BaseClass { };

struct DerivedClass2 : virtual public BaseClass
{
    DerivedClass2()
    {
        cout<<"hello world of derived class"<<endl;
    }
};

int main() {

    //when you create a member of Base Class it calls just its own constructor. 
    cout<<"Creating an object of BaseClass  : "<<endl;
    BaseClass a;
    cout<<"Done \n \n";

    //when you create a member of Derived class1 it calls constructor of base class      once and then calls
    //its own constructor but as nothing is defined in its default constructor nothing      is printed.
    cout<<"Creating an object of DerivedClass1 (Pure Virtual)  : "<<endl;
    DerivedClass1 b;
    cout<<"Done \n \n";

    //when you create a member of Derived class2 it calls constructor of base class once and then calls
    //its own constructor because its derived. (See how hello world is printed twice , one for base and one for derived)
    cout<<"Creating an object of DerivedClass2  : "<<endl;
    DerivedClass2 c;
    cout<<"Done \n \n";

    getch();
    return 0;
 }
```

Here is the output http://codepad.org/zT3I1VMu
Hope it helps!

Comment: Avoid using hard tabs, especially when mixed with spaces.

Comment: I generally append `<<endl;`  but yes thanks :)